# How to change usb/memory card drive icon

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I read some tutorial on how to change the default icon for usb keys and memory cards. Some time ago I followed a tutorial and did it with success but now I don't figure how to it.
When I press cmd+i on a png that I want to use for the drive's icon I don't see the png, I see the default icon of the previewer! In my case is the default icon of justlookin (a software for preview) but if I change it to the default app, I see the default macosx icon!
What's I'm doing wrong??!?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default OS X Way:

1. Control click on the USB drive icon and select "Get Info"
2. Drag the new icon on top of the icon that is in the top left hand corner under the three window buttons.

An even easy way to change icons is to use [LiteIcon](http://www.freemacsoft.net/LiteIcon/). It's a free application that allows you to change icons or restore the originals back if you choose.

Comment: like i say before ,with the default osx way it put the icon of the "preview" app and not the icon itself!!!
i solve using a software call iconbox
bye

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering how to do this in windows
make a file called "autorun.inf"
add this code to the autorun.inf

```
icon=filename.ico
```